# different ways to make queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I wrote a query in my c# program and it works fine when I type it this way:

```
 query = " SELECT sa.f1 sort, fb.f5 dl, fa.f7 sh " +
         " FROM TC_OBJ2LINK with (nolock) " +
         " join tp_zag with (nolock) on tp_zag.f_key = f_obj_KEY " +
         " left join tp_zag_s sa with (nolock) on sa.f_parentkey = tp_zag.f_key and sa.f_row = 1 " +
         " left join tp_zag_f fa with (nolock) on fa.f_parentkey = tp_zag.f_key and fa.f_row = 1 " +
         " left join tp_zag_f fb with (nolock) on fb.f_parentkey = tp_zag.f_key and fb.f_row = 2 " +
         " WHERE F_OBJ_TYPE = 3 ";
```

But it returns an error that *it can't be bound* with `fa.f7` when I wrote it this way:

```
query = @"
         SELECT sa.f1 sort, fb.f5 dl, fa.f7 sh
         FROM TC_OBJ2LINK with (nolock) 
         join tp_zag with (nolock) on tp_zag.f_key = f_obj_KEY 
         left join tp_zag_s sa with (nolock) on sa.f_parentkey = tp_zag.f_key and sa.f_row =1 
         left join tp_zag_f fa with (nolock) on fa.f_parentkey = tp_zag.f_key and fa.f_row = 1 
         left join tp_zag_f fb with (nolock) on fb.f_parentkey = tp_zag.f_key and fb.f_row = 2
         WHERE F_OBJ_TYPE = 3 ";
```

What is difference between this 2 queries? And why I get an error in the second query?

Answer (score 2):

In the second query despite the fact that you have written your query in multiple lines there isn't any space between them like in the first one. Hence you have syntax errors in the second query. The operator `@` is used, when we want to make a string verbatim.

As it is stated [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html):

> Literals are how you hard-code strings into C# programs. There are two
>   types of string literals in C# - regular string literals and verbatim
>   string literals. Regular string literals are similar to those in many
>   other languages such as Java and C - they start and end with ", and
>   various characters (in particular, " itself, \, and carriage return
>   (CR) and line feed (LF)) need to be "escaped" to be represented in the
>   string. Verbatim string literals allow pretty much anything within
>   them, and end at the first " which isn't doubled. Even carriage
>   returns and line feeds can appear in the literal! To obtain a " within
>   the string itself, you need to write "". Verbatim string literals are
>   distinguished by having an @ before the opening quote. Here are some
>   examples of the two types of literal, and what they amount to:

The error you have in terms of code is that the following:

```
SELECT sa.f1 sort, fb.f5 dl, fa.f7 sh
FROM TC_OBJ2LINK with (nolock)
```

will be interpreted as

```
SELECT sa.f1 sort, fb.f5 dl, fa.f7 shFROM TC_OBJ2LINK with (nolock)
```

Comment: I see, so how I need to correct my query if I don't want to use + between lines?

Comment: @Christos: adding space to end of lines does not solve his problem?

Comment: @alexander.skibin  actually you don't have to use the `@` operator here. I mean I don't see any benefit of doing so. I would stick with the first query. However, if you want to use it anyway, you just at the end of each line to place this `\n`. This will indicate that a newline begins and your query will be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't directly do that, but I feel you're asking about `@` here. Yes, it handles the escaping for you, but you change the whole string and there's no character to be escaped in it. At this situations, try printing the string on the screen and see its actual value to solve the mysteries.